# Import SCSS Files as typescript-module

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, typescript-typings

I wanted to update my angular project to the latest version 13.1.0. After I did the update, my app is not working any longer. It fails when I try to import my scss-module which worked before with the following code:
globals.d.ts:

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: { [className: string]: string };
  export default content;
}
```

And then in my service: `import * as styles from '../../styles.scss';`
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve that ?

Comment: sorry for the late response - i was not able to solve this